# Transforming list of documents into corpus

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

Im doing the following tutorial on text mining: http://www.r-bloggers.com/text-mining-the-complete-works-of-william-shakespeare/

Everything is quite clear but there one thing i do not get:

At a certain moment the list of documents is converted into a corpus:

```
doc.vec <- VectorSource(shakespeare)
doc.corpus <- Corpus(doc.vec)
```

Could anybody explain to me in plain English (preferable with an example) what's happing under the hood here?

Comment: Essentially, a corpus contains a set of documents, each of which documents has words in it (plus, possibly, various kinds of meta data about the corpus).  The next step, usually creating a term document matrix [tdm] from that corpus, looks at each word (term) and how many times it is used in each document of the corpus.  That creates a sparse matrix, with documents as columns and rows as terms, since many, many of the terms do not appear in lots of the documents (lots of zeros in the matrix, in other words).  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that the trouble comes from the `VectorSource` part of the code : why do we need this extra step to create a corpus?

Corpuses are R object that hold text and metadata. They are created by the function `tm::Corpus`. It basically transforms a collection of texts into a well-formatted object that other text mining function are able to understand.

However, documents can come in many different forms. Let's consider two of them.

- The documents are a bunch of text files on your computer, each holding one document.
- The documents are stored in a character vector in R, each observation being a document.

The function `Corpus` is not able to differentiate those two sources by itself. This is where the various `Source` functions come in. They preformat the documents according to the kind of source, so that `Corpus` is able to understand it.

If, for instance, what you had was a directory named `shakespeare` on your computer, with one text file for each play (`midsummer.txt`, `hamlet.txt`, etc.), you would create your corpus like this :

```
corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(directory="/path/to/shakespeare"))
```

This would read the files one by one and add them as documents to the corpus.

If, as is the case in your tutorial, those documents had already been read into R, through `readLines` for instance, and were made into a data.frame.

```
shakespeare <- data.frame(title=c("midsummer","hamlet"),
                          text=c("Love looks not with the eyes...","to be or not to be..."))
```

Then you would have to adjust and use `VectorSource`

```
corpus(VectorSource(shakespeare$text))
```

For more information, read `?Source` and `?Corpus`. You will see that there are other possibles sources, but I personally never use them.

Answer (score 0):

The Corpus is the main structure of the tm package. Think it as a data structure, used in tm for your list of documents. Later on all your text mining analytics and insights are going to result from transformations done to your Corpus.
If you want to read and understand in more details I would suggest you to read:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf
Hope it helps!